# QGis 2.2 layer buggy in 2.3 master

Tags: qgis, qgis-2, debugging

Wondering if anyone else can reproduce this kind of problem? I dual boot windows 7 and ubuntu 13.04 with QGis on both. Have updated QGis to latest on both, and created a layer in my project in 2.2 in Windows (voronoi polygons with 5 data layers). When opened in ubuntu it displays fine, but if I edit the style at all the layer disappears.

EDIT: Checked in 2.3 in Windwos 7 and had the same problem, so it's a problem with master not ubuntu/windows. Title changed accordingly.

[Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wYTJ2.jpg) to imgur album explaining it. Image sequence: 1: version. 2: appearance when opened fresh. Looks fine. 3: details of that layer: 25 equal counts on the first data layer. 4: changed to pretty breaks and hit apply - layer disappears in background, data field now blank. 5: but no blank data field present.

Reminds me of similar bugs I've found before e.g. [blank data fields](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/72284/why-are-some-values-missing-from-the-imported-csv)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bug in current master - http://hub.qgis.org/issues/10179